# Storing & returning generic type (even void) from function

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a RPC system designed to execute tasks in remote processes. One node of the RPC system is Monitor that should log every call.

```
template<typename Transport, typename Journal>
class Monitor
{
public:
    Monitor(Transport transport, Journal &journal) :
        transport{std::move(transport)},
        journal{journal}
    {
    }

public:
    template<typename Method>
    typename Method::Result operator()(const Method &method)
    {
        Method::Result result;
        journal("->", Method::Name());
        result = transport(method);
        journal("<-", Method::Name());
        return result;
    }

private:
    Transport transport;
    Journal &journal;
};
```

It works fine except one case when Method::Result is void. To work around this I had to split operator() into 2 parts

```
template<typename Transport, typename Journal>
template<typename Method>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename Method::Result, void>::value, typename Method::Result> operator()(const Method &method)
{
    journal("->", Method::Name());
    transport(method);
    journal("<-", Method::Name());
}

template<typename Transport, typename Journal>
template<typename Method>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<typename Method::Result, void>::value, typename Method::Result> operator()(const Method &method)
{
    Method::Result result; 
    journal("->", Method::Name());
    result = transport(method);
    journal("<-", Method::Name());
    return result;
}
```

Is there any way to eliminate copy-paste, assuming that line `journal("<-", Method::Name());` should not be executed in case of an exception (so I can't wrap logging in construct/destructor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* wrap logging inside a RAII object. Just check whether an exception is currently in flight before printing in the destructor, which can be done with [`std::uncaught_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception) (which will become `std::uncaught_exceptions` in C++17).

---

If something more flexible is needed, you can use a wrapper for your return value, specializing it for `void`:

```
template <class T>
struct RetWrapper {
    template <class Tfunc, class... Targs>
    RetWrapper(Tfunc &&func, Targs &&... args)
    : val(std::forward<Tfunc>(func)(std::forward<Targs>(args)...)) {}

    T &&value() { return std::move(val); }

private:
    T val;
};

template <>
struct RetWrapper<void> {
    template <class Tfunc, class... Targs>
    RetWrapper(Tfunc &&func, Targs &&... args) {
        std::forward<Tfunc>(func)(std::forward<Targs>(args)...);
    }

    void value() {}
};
```

`RetWrapper` performs the function call and stores the result, which can later be moved out via `value()`. This ties in with the possibility of returning a `void`-type expression from a `void` function:

```
template<typename Method>
typename Method::Result operator()(const Method &method)
{
    journal("->", Method::Name());
    RetWrapper<typename Method::Result> retVal{transport, method};
    journal("<-", Method::Name());
    return retVal.value();
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ce9b4617f3aa116)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Have never heard about std::uncaught_exception before. The only downside is that check is performed in runtime and I have to pay performance penalty for it